# PreferenceActivity в API 25

Tags: java, android, activity, android-preferences

Вычитал в интернете про создание активити настроек для приложения. Во всех статьях, что я нашёл использовался метод `addPreferencesFromResource()`:

```
public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
    }
}
```

Но как оказалось, этот метод deprecated, из-за чего возникает вопрос: как создаётся активити настроек в версии API 25?

**UPD:** Сделал всё как написано ответе, котрый дал @Regent, но при попытке запуска акивити настроек приложение закрывается, вылазит окно "приложение остановлено". PrefFragment.java:

```
package com.evgeniy.calc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;


public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

PrefActivity.java:

```
package com.evgeniy.calc;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

import java.util.List;


public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preferences, target);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PrefFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }
}
```

Вызов активити настроек в MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.action_about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `addPreferencesFromResource` должен быть в Preference Fragment. В [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23545532/3432401) на английском SO представлен развёрнутый пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод deprecated, потому что сейчас для этого предлагается использовать [PreferenceFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html). Подробнее об этом написано в [руководстве](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment).

Если коротко, то так:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```